# Read a line from a stream

Tags: performance, c, strings, io

Since the standard `fgets()` does not suffice for my use cases, as it doesn't automatically enlarge the target buffer if needed, and `getline()`/`fgetln()` are not part of the C standard, I rolled out my own.

### Code:

The code below is listed as one file for code review.

```
#define TEST_MAIN // Or pass this with make/gcc.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Reads the next line from the stream pointed to by `stream`.
 *
 * The line is terminated by a NUL character.
 * On success, the memory pointed to by `len` shall contain the length of the line 
 * (including the terminating NUL character).
 * The returned line does not contain a newline.
 *
 * Upon successful completion a pointer is returned, otherwise NULL is returned.
 * `fgetline()` does not distinguish between end-of-file and error; the routines
 * `feof()` and `ferror()` must be used to determine which occurred.
 */
char *fgetline(FILE *stream, size_t *len)
{
    clearerr(stream);

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 0;
    size_t size = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            char *const tmp = realloc(line, capacity += BUFSIZ);
            
            if (!tmp) {
                free(line);
                return NULL;
            }

            line = tmp;
        }
        
        if (!fgets(line + size, BUFSIZ, stream)) {
            if (ferror(stream)) {
                free(line);
                return NULL;
            } 
            break;
        }

        if (strpbrk(line, "\n\r")) {
            break;
        }

        size += BUFSIZ;
    }
    
    if (feof(stream) && size == 0) {
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* TODO: Shrink the memory chunk here. */ 
    *len = strcspn(line, "\n\r"); 
    line[*len] = '\0';
    *len += 1;
    return line;
}

#ifdef TEST_MAIN

#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(argv[1]);
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    assert(fp);
    
    size_t size = 0;

    assert(!strcmp(fgetline(fp, &size), "12"));
    assert(size == 3);

    assert(!strcmp(fgetline(fp, &size), "AB"));
    assert(size == 3);

    assert(!strcmp(fgetline(fp, &size), "123"));
    assert(size == 4);

    assert(!strcmp(fgetline(fp, &size), "ABC"));
    assert(size == 4);

    assert(!strcmp(fgetline(fp, &size), "1234"));
    assert(size == 5);

    assert(!strcmp(fgetline(fp, &size), "ABCD"));
    assert(size == 5);

    rewind(fp);
    char *res = NULL;

    while ((res = fgetline(fp, &size)) != NULL) {
        printf("Line read: \"%s\", line length: %zu, string length: %zu\n", res, size, strlen(res));
    }

    assert(!fgetline(fp, &size));
    assert(feof(fp));    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
#endif /* TEST_MAIN */
```

prints:

```
Line read: "12", line length: 3, string length: 2
Line read: "AB", line length: 3, string length: 2
Line read: "123", line length: 4, string length: 3
Line read: "ABC", line length: 4, string length: 3
Line read: "1234", line length: 5, string length: 4
Line read: "ABCD", line length: 5, string length: 4
Line read: "", line length: 1, string length: 0
```

where the sample text file contained:

```
12
AB
123
ABC
1234
ABCD
^@^@^@^@
```

The last line contains 4 NUL characters, courtesy of `fputc(0, fp)`.

### Review Request:

Are there any bugs in the code?

Are there any edge cases I have missed?

Does the function provide what's expected of a *good* line-reading function?

If there are embedded NUL characters in the line, the function returns the string up to the first NUL character. Was that a bad decision to take?

Comment: If you map the file to memory, you can return a line as a string slice, and then parse or copy it. This has some drawbacks (reading a new page of the file might be slow on some OSes, won’t work on streams such as a network, console or pipe), but if can simplify this operation a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A real good *get line* function is tricky and sadly missing in standard C.

---

> Are there any bugs in the code?

See below.

> Are there any edge cases I have missed?

See below.

> Does the function provide what's expected of a good line-reading function?

Overall a fairly good effort.  Yet buffer allocating `O(n*n)` and use of `clearerr()` are amiss.

> If there are embedded NUL characters in the line, the function returns the string up to the first `NUL` character. Was that a bad decision to take?

A *get line* function that returns length should be able to cope with reading null characters.  If not, why have a `len` parameter as calling code can simply perform `strlen()` to determine the length?

---

**Questionable `clearerr(stream)`?**

`fgets()`, `fscanf()` and others do not clear the *error* flag and *end-of-file* flags.  The choice to do that is usually left to the calling code, not the *get line* code.  I'd expect `fgetline()` to correctly operate with the error and end-of-file flags in either state upon function entry and to not employ a `clearerr()`.

Concerning `if (ferror(stream)) {`,  consider using `if (!feof(stream)) {` to not get fooled by an end-of-file with the error flag set prior to this call.
[Is it possible to distinguish the error returned by fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264457/2410359)

**`*len` on failure**

Code has "On success, the memory pointed to by `len` shall contain the length of the line ...", but is silent on what happens when the is a failure.  Perhaps add that `*len` is unchanged on failure.

Consider `*len` should be set in all cases with 0 on failure.

**Code assumes a *null character* is not read**

`strpbrk(line, "\n\r")` and `strcspn(line, "\n\r")` will not detect data read beyond the first `'\0'` in the buffer.  There will be multiple `'\0'` in `line` when a *null character* is read, the ones read and the one appended.

Properly handling the reading of a *null character* is tricky.

**Bug?: Code assumes a `'\r'` ends the line**

`strpbrk(line, "\n\r")` and `strcspn(line, "\n\r")` performed as if the line stopped at `'\r'`.  Consider a line of user input such as `"abc\rdef\r\n"`.

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. ...  C23dr § 7.23.2 2

What makes for a *raw* terminating new-line character varies between systems - it is implementation dependent.  Trying to make a universal detector of line terminator is tricky should code encounter *text* files from local and "foreign" sources.

**File open in *binary* mode?**

If this `fgetline()` *requires* the stream is opened in *text* or *binary*, that requirement needs to be documented.  Better if the function works well in either case.

**Redundant work**

`*len = strcspn(line, "\n\r")` rescans the initial portion of `line` that is known not to contain `"\n\r"`.  Something like `*len = strcspn(line + (size - BUFSIZ), "\n\r") + (size - BUFSIZ);` can avoid that.

**Surprising "length"**

`*len += 1;` does follow "all contain the length of the line * (including the terminating NUL character)." yet maybe something other than *length* is warranted - like *size* or *count* or ....  With strings, "length" is tied closely to the return value of `strlen()` and that differs by 1 here.

FWIW, I see advantages of code returning this + 1 count, especially when code changed to set the `*len` to 0 on error.

**Minor: `NUL` vs. *null character*`**

Consider using *null character*.

C defines *null character* and only uses `NUL` in a footnote referring to ASCII.

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) defines `NUL`.

**When `NULL` is returned**

I see 3 cases:

- End-of-file  and nothing read.
- Input error
- Memory allocation failure.

The last case is not documented in the `fgetline()` preface.

**Minor: Big buffers**

`BUFSIZ` is *at least* 256 so each line read can have a cumulative significant extra size.  Consider a final `realloc()` to right-size the buffer - or warn about these inefficient allocations.

I suppose that is all implied with the `TODO: Shrink the memory chunk here`.

**Minor: buffer growth**

`line` grows linearly and so can make for `O(len*len)` for *long* lines.  More complexity, but other approaches have advantages.

One way that is `O(len)` is to form a linked list of `BUFSIZ` buffers and then collect them as one in the end.

**Testing**

Code only tested in binary mode with `FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");`, yet `fgetline()` more likely used in *text* mode.

**.h file**

Consider a preceding

```
#include < ... >
// documentation
char *fgetline(FILE *stream, size_t *len);
```

and then

```
#include < ... >
char *fgetline(FILE *stream, size_t *len) {
```

To convey how one would present this function in a typical header file.

Comment: "Re: strpbrk(line, "\n\r") and strcspn(line, "\n\r") will not detect data read beyond the first '\0' in the buffer." ==> Yes. Do you have an alternate method with the current approach? Or do I read byte by byte?

Comment: Rewriting it to read byte-by-byte cut down the code size by half and took care of the embedded null characters.

Comment: @Harith Byte-by-byte has a performance hit vs. `fgets()`.  `fgets()` without a pre-fill makes it hard to find those _null characters_, `fscanf(f, "%width[^n]%n", buf, &len)` _works_ but is not size flexible and likely slow.  IMO, there is not a good clean line input function in C.  User code solutions incur some weakness.  For a input function that allocates, consider *nix's `getline()` (and lift its source code when your system does not have it) - . It has weaknesses - but at least there is a chance it will perform well.

Comment: @Harith "Do you have an alternate method with the current approach?" --> For a non-allocating version, I have had some success with `fscanf(f, "%width[^n]%n", buf, &len)`.  IMO, input that exceeds the caller's maximum expected input should read the whole line, yet is an error - and so the whole line need not get saved.  This prevents the end-user from overwhelming memory usage.  My model is to be flexible, yet user input is _evil_ until vetted.

Comment: This sample implementation of `getline()`: https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/contrib/file/getline.c reads byte-by-byte with `fgetc()`.

Comment: @Harith that has a memory leak with pathologic code `p = malloc(100); size_t n = 0;  getline(&p, &n, stdin);`.  Fixable with `free(*buf)` before `if ((*buf = malloc(*bufsiz)) == NULL)`.

Comment: "_why have a `len` parameter as calling code can simply perform `strlen()` to determine the length?_"  encourages inefficient coding styles.  The length is a useful by-product of work we're already doing, so let's not repeat the error of `strcat()`!  It would be better if `len` were optional so that code that doesn't use it could pass a null pointer instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight OP used `fgets()`.  "The length is a useful by-product of work we're already doing," does not apply to `fgets()`.  If code what to detect _null characters_, then other approaches are needed and in those cases length is found and perhaps a useful by-product.  So if code does not care about reading _null characters_, obliging to return a length can simple be extra work that is not needed as, again, `fgets()` does not give use length for free.